# Is there any CodeLens add-on available that shows the git history of the given method?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, codelens

The latest version of **VS 2019 Community** came out with CodeLens enabled. Is there any CodeLens add-on available for **VS 2019 Community** showing the git history of the given method, like this excellent one for **Visual Studio Code**: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I click on the history link of code lens in Enterprise:

[image]

I see a history listing. I have not added any extensions to get this. (Do ensure "Show Authors & Changes (Git)" is enabled in Options | Text Editor | All Languages | Code Lens.)

Previously when Code Lens was added to Professional it was added with full functionality, I have assumed the same applies to Community.

***Edit***

It turns out that Community Edition has a reduced code lens:

> The source control CodeLens indicators are not available in Visual Studio Community edition.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no in-build support for git history in CodeLens in VS 2019 Community.

Comment: @romanoza This time I found the right information in the docs.