# Visual studio, nickname of the person who made the change

Tags: github, workflow

I am working with some people, sharing the same Github repository. We decided that we want to know who made which script or edited some code line easily. The best way will be the initials of the person who made the change next to the code. I know in Rider it's possible because I saw that when I worked in some company. I think it's some kind of cooperation with Github. Does anybody know how to add something like this in VS 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with Github, then you want to use Git as a Configuration Management tool. This way, each member of your team will be able to retrieve content from Github, and push updates through Git commands.
When you setup your working environment the first time, you configure your Name and EmailAddress. These information is then available to identify who made each change in Github.
Read the basic setup here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

> Your Identity
> The first thing you should do when you install Git is to set your user name and email address. This is important because every Git commit uses this information, and it’s immutably baked into the commits you start creating:

> $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"

> $ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com

**Edit:**

Sorry I did not get your question indeed. The same thing has been asked here: [Is there any CodeLens add-on available that shows the git history of the given method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610991/is-there-any-codelens-add-on-available-that-shows-the-git-history-of-the-given-m)

I would add that what your are looking for is a presentation of the **git blame** command, which shows who modified which line. You can access this within Visual Studio through right click source file/Source Control/Annotate. This is less practical than CodeLens since you have to click a few times, but does the job.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think you didn't understand. I know how to use git (in a basic way maybe I am missing something?)

Let's say I made some code. After a week I have seen that one function was added. I want to know who made it. Best way is just to see initials next to this function. I saw solution like that so i know it's possible. Question is how do i made it?

Comment: Good example of extensions that do that is GitLens. Problem is that I am using VS teams 2019 not code one.